# Uses unchecked or unsafe operations error preventing apk building

Tags: java, android

I was trying to `implement` a `sectionedRecyclerAdapter` in my app and got it working. However when i want to generate `apk` its says an

> error "uses unchecked or unsafe operations" in 
>   SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter class.

It does not provide any line number or method name so I am unable to `debug` it. How can I resolve this.

My class is

```
public class SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {



private final Context mContext;
private static final int SECTION_TYPE = 0;

private boolean mValid = true;
private int mSectionResourceId;
private int mTextResourceId;

private RecyclerView.Adapter mBaseAdapter;
private SparseArray<Section> mSections = new SparseArray<Section>();


public SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, int sectionResourceId, int textResourceId,
                                          RecyclerView.Adapter baseAdapter) {


    mSectionResourceId = sectionResourceId;
    mTextResourceId = textResourceId;
    mBaseAdapter = baseAdapter;
    mContext = context;

    mBaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            mValid = mBaseAdapter.getItemCount()>0;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            mValid = mBaseAdapter.getItemCount()>0;
            notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            mValid = mBaseAdapter.getItemCount()>0;
            notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            mValid = mBaseAdapter.getItemCount()>0;
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
        }
    });
}


public static class SectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView title;

    public SectionViewHolder(View view, int mTextResourceid) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(mTextResourceid);
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int typeView) {
    if (typeView == SECTION_TYPE) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(mSectionResourceId, parent, false);
        return new SectionViewHolder(view,mTextResourceId);
    }else{
        return mBaseAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(parent, typeView -1);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder sectionViewHolder, int position) {
    if (isSectionHeaderPosition(position)) {
        ((SectionViewHolder)sectionViewHolder).title.setText(mSections.get(position).title);
    }else{
        mBaseAdapter.onBindViewHolder(sectionViewHolder,sectionedPositionToPosition(position));
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return isSectionHeaderPosition(position)
            ? SECTION_TYPE
            : mBaseAdapter.getItemViewType(sectionedPositionToPosition(position)) +1 ;
}


public static class Section {
    int firstPosition;
    int sectionedPosition;
    CharSequence title;

    public Section(int firstPosition, CharSequence title) {
        this.firstPosition = firstPosition;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public CharSequence getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}


public void setSections(Section[] sections) {
    mSections.clear();

    Arrays.sort(sections, new Comparator<Section>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Section o, Section o1) {
            return (o.firstPosition == o1.firstPosition)
                    ? 0
                    : ((o.firstPosition < o1.firstPosition) ? -1 : 1);
        }
    });

    int offset = 0; // offset positions for the headers we're adding
    for (Section section : sections) {
        section.sectionedPosition = section.firstPosition + offset;
        mSections.append(section.sectionedPosition, section);
        ++offset;
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int positionToSectionedPosition(int position) {
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mSections.size(); i++) {
        if (mSections.valueAt(i).firstPosition > position) {
            break;
        }
        ++offset;
    }
    return position + offset;
}

public int sectionedPositionToPosition(int sectionedPosition) {
    if (isSectionHeaderPosition(sectionedPosition)) {
        return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
    }

    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mSections.size(); i++) {
        if (mSections.valueAt(i).sectionedPosition > sectionedPosition) {
            break;
        }
        --offset;
    }
    return sectionedPosition + offset;
}

public boolean isSectionHeaderPosition(int position) {
    return mSections.get(position) != null;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return isSectionHeaderPosition(position)
            ? Integer.MAX_VALUE - mSections.indexOfKey(position)
            : mBaseAdapter.getItemId(sectionedPositionToPosition(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (mValid ? mBaseAdapter.getItemCount() + mSections.size() : 0);
}

}
```

Comment: Does it give you a line number?

Comment: @TheWanderer no it doesnt